# it it possible to compile a single tex file to pdf

Tags: xetex, subfiles

I am now using `\include` to connect each single .tex as a whole book. Now I just want to compile one of the section of the book as a single pdf, is there any way to do this? I am already tried pandoc like this:

```
pandoc jenkins-kubernetes.tex --pdf-engine=xelatex -o jenkins.pdf
```

but the output of the pdf with a bad formats and did not support chinese words. is there any better way to archive this? I am reference the tex file like this:

```
\section{Chaos}

\input{chapter-2020-04/chaos/flutter/enterprise.tex}
\input{chapter-2020-04/chaos/http/self-sign-certificate.tex}
\input{chapter-2020-04/chaos/http/auto-update-certificate.tex}
\input{chapter-2020-04/chaos/http/cert-problem.tex}
```

Comment: If the included files are `one.tex`, `two.tex`, `three.tex`, etc., and you include them via `\incude{one}`, `\include{two}`, etc., you can compile one or more of these, for example,  using `\includeonly{one,three}`, `\includeonly{two}`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `subfiles` package you create subfiles for each chapter of the book an then compile every subfile independently, until is error free. Each subfile is self-sufficient: it will automatically use the preamble in the main file.

The debugging is much faster, because using `\input` or `\include` the errors messages many times point to the wrong line number.
Also, it will not be necessary to compile it twice, since it is not necessary to generate a table of contents.

There are four possible cases to test how it works:

To begin put `main.tex` in a brand new directory. Create inside a subdirectory `chapters` and put `chap1.tex` and `chap2.tex` in there.

(1) Compile `main.tex` commenting both `\subfile{./chapters/chap1}` and  `\subfile{./chapters/chap2}` from `main.tex`

It will generate `main.pdf` with the title, the TOC and the chapter "Introduction", as expected, after two compiles.

(2) Compile `chap1.tex` keeping commented `\subfile{./chapters/chap1}`  and  `\subfile{./chapters/chap2}` in `main.tex`

It will generate `chap1.pdf` in the `chapters` directory, using `main.tex` preamble. Get a similar result compiling `chap2.tex`

There will be no Title, TOC or Introduction, so it will be  faster to compile. In the real life you use this  capability to debug both files. The error messages will point to the right lines of the code.

(3) Run `main.tex`, now un-commenting  `\subfile{./chapters/chap1}` and `\subfile{./chapters/chap2}`

It will  run twice (because of the TOC) and will generate `main.pdf`  in the root directory, complete with title page, table of contents and all  the chapters.

(4 Delete  files from the root directory except `main.tex` and compile `chap1.tex`.

It will  run twice, as before, and will  generate `main.pdf` in the root directory, complete with title page, table of contents and all  the chapters, as in (3).

This is `main.tex` of a book prototype:

```
%% main.tex in its own directory

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{subfiles} %<<<<<<<<<<< added
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % dummy text

\author{The Author}
\title{The BooK Title}
\begin{document}
    
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Introduction} 
0. \kant[1-6]   

\subfile{./chapters/chap1}  % chapter #1 file in  root/chapters directory

\subfile{./chapters/chap2} %chapter #2 file in  root/chapters directory
    
\end{document}
```

This is the `chap1.tex` file

```
 %% chap1.tex in "chapters" directory  will compile using main.tex preamble

\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}

\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
1. \kant[2-7]

\end{document}
```

and this the `chap2.tex` file

```
%% chap2.tex in "chapters" directory  will compile using main.tex preamble

\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Two}
2. \kant[7-8]   
\end{document
```